# Spring’s CacheControl builder with both no-cache and no-store

Tags: spring

It seems that the `CacheControl` header builder from the Spring framework is not able to create headers with both `no-cache` and `no-store` set: The methods that set those values are static and both create a fresh builder. What is the point of this (Spring Security always sets both)? What is an elegant workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java docs explain the difference and why you don't need both

[noStore](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/CacheControl.java) is a complete disable operation

> In order to **disable caching** and minimize requests/responses exchanges,
>         the `noStore()` directive should be used instead of `noCache()`

While `noCache` is lighter:

> "no-cache" directive.
>        This directive is well suited for telling caches that the response
>        can be reused only if the client revalidates it with the server.
>        **This directive won't disable cache altogether and may result with clients
>        sending conditional requests**

Comment: Well, I wouldn’t really trust the JavaDoc on that. But it seems that [MDN agrees](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), and therefore, this is the accepted answer.